# Parse result into JSON using Python and Flask

Tags: python, json, api, iot, smart-device

Now, I managed to successfully pull basic information from my smart device onto the terminal using pyHS100 on python (v3.6) using the following code

```
from pyHS100 import SmartPlug
from pprint import pformat as pf
plug = SmartPlug("10.xxx.xxx.xxx")
print("Hardware: %s" % pf(plug.hw_info))
```

which results in the following:

[image]

but I can't parse the data into json format and display it on the local server for my RESTful API purpose if I done it this way:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from pyHS100 import SmartPlug

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api')
def get():
    plug = SmartPlug("10.xxx.xxx.xxx")
    sys = plug.hw_info
    return jsonify({'data':sys})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

All I need is for the information to be presented into something like this:

[image]

[image]
What did I do wrong and how do I this fix? Thanks

Comment: Please fix your indentation and show the traceback

Comment: Got it. Please see the above

Comment: That traceback doesn't reference your code at all. My best guess is that you have some mismatch between flask and werkzeug because it looks like it's separate from your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way to solving this is by using json.dumps